# WordPress - custom templates not loading css and js and head tag is empty

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a problem after using `template_include` hook to assign a custom template to `query_var`

```
add_action( 'template_include', function( $template ) {
  if ( (get_query_var( 'checklist_slug' ) == false || get_query_var( 'checklist_slug' ) == '') && (get_query_var( 'checklist_action' ) == false || get_query_var( 'checklist_action' ) == '')) {
      return $template;
  }

  return get_template_directory() . '/includes/checklist_edit.php';
});
```

even when I use `is_page_template` to enqueue the scripts and stylesheets it's not working

```
function uxwithmarwan_files() {
  wp_enqueue_script('main-university-js', get_theme_file_uri('/build/index.js'), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
  wp_enqueue_style('custom-google-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,700');
  wp_enqueue_style('university_main_styles', get_theme_file_uri('/build/style-index.css'));
  wp_enqueue_script('font-awesome', 'https://kit.fontawesome.com/5d2df7d4f7.js');
  if ( is_page_template('includes/checklist_create.php') ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('main-university-js', get_theme_file_uri('/build/index.js'), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_style('custom-google-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,700');
    wp_enqueue_style('university_main_styles', get_theme_file_uri('/build/style-index.css'));
    wp_enqueue_script('font-awesome', 'https://kit.fontawesome.com/5d2df7d4f7.js');
  }
  if ( is_page_template('includes/checklist_edit.php') ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('main-university-js', get_theme_file_uri('/build/index.js'), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_style('custom-google-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,700');
    wp_enqueue_style('university_main_styles', get_theme_file_uri('/build/style-index.css'));
    wp_enqueue_script('font-awesome', 'https://kit.fontawesome.com/5d2df7d4f7.js');
  } 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'uxwithmarwan_files');
```

as you see here the template doesn't load any files except the index
[image of loaded sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phfAm.png)
and `<head>` tag is totally empty
[image of empty head tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9eQu.png)

Comment: Are you calling the [`wp_head()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/) function anywhere? That function is required to initialize all the enqueueing magic that goes in with [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/)

Comment: WTF!!!!!! I totally forgot to call it I spent two hours searching for nothing, and the solution was in front of me. thank you @Xhynk

Comment: @Xhynk please write an answer to accept it as a correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) hook (or any others that automatically drop code into the "header" or "footer" of the site, you'll need to make sure that the [`wp_head()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/) is called in your templates or template parts, as well as the the [`wp_footer()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/).

The `wp_footer()` function is going to be required namely if you're using the `$in_footer` boolean argument for your [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function calls!